# Exclude Custom post type from /blog page

Tags: custom-post-types, exclude, blog-page

Custom post type name is "project". I need code in functions.php

This is working for search:

```
// Exclude custom post type from  WP Search
add_action( 'init', 'update_my_custom_type', 99 );
function update_my_custom_type() {
    global $wp_post_types;

    if ( post_type_exists( 'project' ) ) {
        // exclude from search results
        $wp_post_types['project']->exclude_from_search = true;
    }
}
```

I can not find a solution for /blog page.

Comment: Custom post types should not appear on the blog page. Is the blog page the page set to the page for posts in Settings > Reading? Or is it implemented another way, such as through a custom template.

Comment: After better search i didn't found any custom post on my /blog page. You are right, they are not displayed at all there. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one

```
function exclude_some_post_type($query) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        if ( $query->is_search || is_home() ) {
            // in search page
            $query->set( 'post_type', 'post' );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_some_post_type' );
```

The function that applied to a `pre_get_posts` hook will set only default post type (post), and will ignore the other types in search or blog (home) page.

For further reading about `pre_get_posts` hook, please visit: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/